# How to ignore 32 chars in URL withe a regular expression

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need to set up the steps funnel in my google analytics, but for that, in the URL I'm trying to find some way to ignore 32 chars between the "example.com/39921713197/checkouts/" - and -"?previous_step=contact_information&step=shipping_method".
In this case ignore 32 characters normally arranged in this format (not constant): "b625d2e28d1c2f14bfdbf8e051787cb4".

What regular expression should I use to ignore that? and how?

already try: [a-z0-9], (.)+

My full URL:
example.com/39921713197/checkouts/b625d2e28d1c2f14bfdbf8e051787cb4?previous_step=contact_information&step=shipping_method

Comment: does splitting on the first `?` help?

Comment: could you give me an example please?

Comment: perhaps `/[a-f\d]{32}\?(.+)$`

Comment: @ti7, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment a complete answer; perhaps just finding the 32 chars and splitting on `?` would work!

```
/[a-f\d]{32}\?(.+)$
```

- find 32 hex characters
- find a literal `?`
- take make a group of all the remaining characters (at least one) until the end of the string (url)